# Get List of elements from another List with specified ids

Tags: java

I've got a `List<Element> elements`, where class Element has property `id` - it is Long. I have also `List<Long> ids`. Now i need to get from `elements` list objects that have `id` prop that exist in `ids` list.

I used for this two for loops, but i think it is not best option.

How can i improve my performance?

```
 public class Element{

   Long id;

   public Element(Long id){
     this.id = id;
   }

   public Long getId( ){
     return id;
   }

   public static void main(String []args){
     List<Element> elements= Arrays.asList(new Element(1),new Element(2),new Element(3), new Element(5), new Element(5));
     List<Long> ids= Arrays.asList(3,4,1);
     List<Element> returnList = new ArrayList<Alement>();

     for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < ids.size(); j++) {
            if (elements.get(i).getId() == ids.get(j))
                returnList.add(elements.get(i));
        }
     }

   }
 }
```

Comment: *I used for this two for loops* could you post your loops so that we understand what you have done?

Comment: i edited with example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i improve my performance?

You could use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for your elements using the `id` as the key. Then, use a single loop over your `ids` `List` for the lookups.
`HashMap` has a constant lookup complexity.

Comment: `HashSet` would be better.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this since HashSet is backed by a HashMap, can you give me a hint why it'd be better (beside the obvious set property which I agree most likely is desirable by OP)?

Comment: Because a `Set` merely holds a set of items, a `Map` holds `Key/Value` pairs. OP only needs existence not translation from key to value so a `Set` is more appropriate..

Answer (score 1):

Make a set of ids like this:

```
    Set<Long> idSet = new HashSet<>(ids);
    List<Element> selected = elements.stream()
        .filter(element -> idSet.contains(element.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [filtering](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Predicates) for that:

```
    Iterable<Element> filteredElements = Iterables.filter(elements, new Predicate<Element>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Element element) {
            return ids.contains(element.getId());
        }
    });
```